# Repetir registros N veces según lo indicado - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, vistas

Tengo la siguiente inquietud. Actualmente tengo una tabla que posee las siguientes columnas (entre otras que debo mostrar):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna Rep me indica si el valor (value) que se encuentra allí debe ser replicado o no. En este caso se repetiría para los N meses siguientes al mes indicado (month: YYYYMM). Además de esto debo generar un segundo grupo de réplicas pero con signo contrario al presente en la columna value, tanto para el mes actual (el de la tabla original) como para sus respectivas réplicas. Estos valores con signo contrario se deber "registrar" en el mes siguiente en el cual se encausan en el concepto **rep** o **approved**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No soy muy conocedor de las estructuras complejas en Postgres. Estuve revisando algo de literatura y por lo que pude ver existen iteraciones que se se pueden usar en Procedimiento Almacenado, pero en mi caso me piden generar una vista que poseerá este resultado con otras columnas que debo proyectar de otras tablas. Pero no encuentro la manera de generar este primer resultado.

Cual podría ser una buena estrategia para comenzar a resolver esta primera parte de mi desarrollo.

Agradezco de antemano su valiosa colaboración

Comment: El tipo de `month` es `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Y en el ejemplo las lineas rojas empiezan con 201712 pero segun tu explicación deberia ser 201711, no?

Comment: Hola Tao. El month tiene ese formato YYYYMM de tipo integer. Ya aclare lal duda en la redacción. Si el concepto es rep o approved debo colocar un valor con signo cocntrario en el mes siguiente a este, por eso para el id 456 los valores en rojo comienzan desde el 201712.

Comment: Sería mucho mas facil si es de tipo `TIMESTAMP`. Pero si te entendí bien ya lo tienes solucionado?

Comment: Si fuese TIMESTAMP o date, y el formato fuera 'YYYY-MM-01', como se podría solucionar. Yo aún sigo tratando de generar esos datos.

Answer (score 1):

> Si fuese TIMESTAMP o date, y el formato fuera 'YYYY-MM-01', como se podría solucionar.

En general lo que necesitas son los metodos de Postgres que crean conjuntos. Si `month` es de tipo `TIMESTAMP` se puede usar [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-srf.html) para crear una serie de fechas a partir de una fecha especifica.

Para usar `generate_series` a base de un valor de otra tabla lo puedes combinar con `CROSS JOIN`. Asi puedes crear las dos series que necesitas y unir todos los resultados que necesitas con `UNION`.

Asumiendo que la tabla se llama `test`:

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS
SELECT id, month, value, concept FROM test
UNION
SELECT id, generate_series AS month, value, 'rep' AS concept FROM test
CROSS JOIN generate_series(
  month + INTERVAL '1 month',
  month + INTERVAL '1 month' * test.rep,
  '1 month'
)
UNION
SELECT id, generate_series AS month, -value, 'fall' AS concept FROM test
CROSS JOIN generate_series(
  month + INTERVAL '1 month',
  month + INTERVAL '1 month' * (CASE WHEN rep = 0 THEN 0 ELSE rep + 1 END),
  '1 month'
);
```

La segunda serie es un poco mas complicada porque necesitamos una linea mas de lo que esta puesto en `rep` pero solo en caso que `rep` no sea 0.

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2bae1/1)**

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Tao!

Answer (score 1):

Para eso se ocupa `generate_series` que entrega una serie de registros recibiendo el número inicial, la cantidad de elementos y opcionalmente la diferencia entre cada elemento y el siguiente (por defecto, 1). Digamos que `generate_series` te entrega una columna que llamaremos **contador**.

Si haces un join entre tu tabla y `generate_series(0, rep)` la primera fila generará sólo un registro 0 en `contador`. La segunda fila generará los registros `0, 1, 2`:

```
SELECT rep, id, month, contador 
FROM tu_tabla JOIN generate_series(0,rep) as contador

rep | id  | month  | contador
-----------------------------
0   | 123 | 201701 |   0
2   | 456 | 201711 |   0
2   | 456 | 201711 |   1
2   | 456 | 201711 |   2
```

Si tomas tu columna `month` y le concatenas `01` luego puedes castearlo como `date`, y siendo un campo de tipo date, puedes sumarle `contador`  casteándolo como `interval`.

```
SELECT rep, 
       id, 
       month, 
       contador, 
       (month||'01')::date + (contador||' months')::interval as fecha
FROM tu_tabla JOIN generate_series(0,rep) as contador

rep | id  | month  | contador | fecha
---------------------------------------------------
0   | 123 | 201701 |   0      | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
2   | 456 | 201711 |   0      | 2017-11-01 00:00:00
2   | 456 | 201711 |   1      | 2017-12-01 00:00:00
2   | 456 | 201711 |   2      | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

En tu query, tendrías dos partes:

**Para obtener las filas de la tabla actual más las filas adicionales de valor positivo,** harías un join entre tu tabla y la función `generate_series` entre 0 y el valor de `rep`. Cuando `rep` es cero la serie sólo entrega una fila. Cuando es mayor a cero, entregará tantas filas como el valor de `rep`. El valor de la glosa (concept) dependerá de si acaso el valor de `contador` es cero (mantienes la glosa) o distinto a cero (lo reemplazas por `'rep'`).

El punto es: con esta consulta `generate_series` siempre te entregará al menos un registro, por lo que tus filas originales se mantendrán cuando `contador` sea cero.

Por cada fila donde `contador` es distinto a cero, se generará una fila adicional (tantas como el valor de `rep`). En cada una de esas filas adicionales, le habrás sumado el valor de `contador` como un intervalo de un mes.

**Para obtener las filas adicionales de valor negativo**, tienes que hacer una unión con lo anterior omitiendo las filas que tengan `rep` igual a cero.

En la siguiente respuesta definí la tabla origen al vuelo, pero en tu caso no necesitas definir `origen`

```
WITH origen AS (
  SELECT 0 AS rep, 123 AS id, 201701 AS month, 234 AS value, 'approved' AS concept
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS rep, 456 AS id, 201711 AS month, 2000 AS value, 'approved' AS concept
),
intermedio AS (
  SELECT id,
         (MONTH||'01')::date + (contador||' months')::interval fecha,
          value,
          CASE WHEN contador=0 THEN concept 
          ELSE 'rep' END AS concept
  FROM origen JOIN generate_series(0,rep) contador ON 1=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
        (MONTH||'01')::date + ((contador+1)||' months')::interval fecha, 
        -1*value,
        'fall' AS concept
  FROM origen JOIN generate_series(0,rep) contador ON 1=1
  WHERE rep!=0
)
SELECT id, 
      date_part('year',fecha)::text||lpad(date_part('month',fecha)::text,2,'0') as month, 
      value, 
      concept 
FROM intermedio
```

(o sea, sólo necesitas hacer `WITH intermedio AS (...)` reemplazando `origen` por el nombre de la tabla.

Nótese que la subconsulta `intermedio` entrega la fecha completa, por lo que en el resultado final reconstruyo el formato YYYYMM concatenando dos funciones `date_part`.

Comment: Excelente amenadiel!! Muchísimas gracias!